# access guest machine from host with virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have a windows 2008 server running in VirtualBox and the host OS is Windows 7.

From the host OS, I would like to be able to access the guest OS in explorer like this:

```
\\name_of_guest_server\some_shared_folder_on_guest_os
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Yes it is possible. They just have to be on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the

```
 net use [driveletter]: \\[client_name]\[shared_folder_name]
```

function to mount the shared folder and speed things up.

other than that, you can still access it the way you mentioned.